# R: URL function timing out prematurely

Tags: r

I'm currently requesting data, sent back as XML, via the URL function and passing in parameters in the url, as so

```
asset.data <- url("http://www.blah.com/?parameter=value", open = "r")
```

Each request constitutes a vector of length ~10,000. I've had some problems with the request timing out when looped (I'm calling data for about 500 "assets"). I've set the timeout in options to something high (600 seconds, or ten minutes) but still notice that the loop will stop if a call takes longer than 60 seconds or so (definitely less than the 10 minutes I've defined). I feel like I must be missing something about how the connection timeout works - any advice here?

Comment: So the function stops when it hits a particular URL that takes too long to resolve? So you want to proceed processing the other URLs if any fail, right?

Comment: No, I've reduced my asset size to 15 (from my original 500 list) and noticed that it hangs on a different asset every time. For example, it'll make it through the first 7 requests and then hang. When I try it again, it'll go through the first 10 requests.

Comment: No idea re: a solution but if you needed to get the job done, use `try`, or `failwith` and record which succeeded and which don't in a `logical` vector. Then throw this `lapply` in a `do` `while` till all/most are done. That way you're not redoing everything each time. You could even keep track of one that fail several times and skip those entirely because those urls could be down.